# Usar protocolo Stratum no PHP é possível? Existe algum equivalente ao `net.Dial` do Go?

Tags: php, libcurl

Eu queria usar os servidores do Electrum, [listadas aqui](https://1209k.com/bitcoin-eye/ele.php?chain=btc), ele utiliza um protocolo chamado "Stratum", que está [documentado aqui](https://docs.google.com/document/d/17zHy1SUlhgtCMbypO8cHgpWH73V5iUQKk_0rWvMqSNs/edit?hl=en_US), mas nem sei é o mais atualizado.

Eu conseguir "fazer funcionar" utilizando a biblioteca `tls` e o `net` (no caso de não usar TLS) no Golang, como é um teste fiz da seguinte forma:

```
config := &tls.Config{
    InsecureSkipVerify: true,
    // NOTA:
    // O Electrum permite servidores com certificados self-signed!
    // O melhor que posso fazer é um Public Key-Pinning baseado em Trust On First Use.
}

PKHashConfiavel := []byte{0x8c, 0x45, 0x01, 0x95, 0x91, 0xd5, 0x4a, 0x50, 0xc8, 0xf6, 0xac, 0x84, 0xa3, 0xf9, 0x70, 0xb1, 0xa7, 0x3b, 0x7e, 0x51, 0xc6, 0xb1, 0x18, 0x72, 0x64, 0x40, 0x00, 0x29, 0xfd, 0xaa, 0xa7, 0xed, 0xbc, 0x8c, 0xd4, 0x2a, 0xf8, 0xe5, 0xdb, 0x55, 0x5f, 0x09, 0x13, 0x56, 0x55, 0x2f, 0x95, 0x39}

// Se conecta com o servidor
conn, err := tls.Dial("tcp", "electrum.hsmiths.com:50002", config)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}

connState := conn.ConnectionState()
var isConfiavel bool = false

// Verifica a hash do certificado no qual me conectei
for _, cert := range connState.PeerCertificates {
    PKDer, _ := x509.MarshalPKIXPublicKey(cert.PublicKey)
    PKHash := blake2b.Sum384(PKDer)

    if hmac.Equal(PKHashConfiavel, PKHash[:]) {
        isConfiavel = true
    }
}

if isConfiavel {

    // Envia a requisição
    comando := "{\"id\": 1, \"method\": \"blockchain.address.get_history\", \"params\": [\"1DB8zJn99HSVUUwWRCgKxiZV33yPfBSVYr\"]}"
    comando += "\n"

    conn.Write([]byte(comando))

    // Obtêm resposta  
    resposta, _ := bufio.NewReader(conn).ReadString('\n')
    fmt.Print(resposta)

}
```

Isso funciona normalmente e retorna:

```
{"jsonrpc": "2.0", "id": 1, "result": [{"tx_hash": "a7d790a2418fd0b17af37b2896327985d52941a1211de8705c6f16d868885412", "height": 483800}, {"tx_hash": "4ee9dcd51d1d80e6aa021e5503354ec3d4125cf8777894b68056cfef9bc9a818", "height": 483801}]}
```

---

Tentei fazer o mesmo em PHP, com os recursos nativos, neste caso a única solução que vejo seria o cURL, mas ele não funciona por nada.

Mas, também tentei no PHP, sem utilizar TLS, da seguinte maneira:

```
$comando = '{"id": 1, "method": "blockchain.address.get_history", "params": ["1DB8zJn99HSVUUwWRCgKxiZV33yPfBSVYr"]}';

$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'electrum.hsmiths.com');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_PORT , '50001');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);

// Para testes desligamos a verificação de SSL:
// curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1_2);
// curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 1);
// curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
// curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_PINNEDPUBLICKEY, 'sha256//' . base64_encode($PKHash))

// Testes fracassados:
//curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, ['Content-Type: application/stratum']);

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $comando);


$response = curl_exec($curl);

var_dump($response);
```

Resposta:

```
string(134) "{"jsonrpc": "2.0", "id": null, "error": {"message": "cannot decode JSON: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)", "code": -32700}}"
```

---

Aparentemente o Stratum não pode ser utilizado sobre o HTTP e para isso eu preciso criar um conexão TCP sem o cURL.

Logo, existe algum equivalente ao `tls.Dial`/`net.Dial` no PHP? Existe alguma alternativa ao cURL e que esteja embutido nativamente no PHP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consegui fazer usando `socket_*`, da seguinte maneira:

```
$socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP);
$conn = socket_connect($socket,  gethostbyname('electrum.hsmiths.com'), '50001');

$comando = '{"id": 1, "method": "blockchain.address.get_history", "params": ["1DB8zJn99HSVUUwWRCgKxiZV33yPfBSVYr"]}' . "\n";

socket_write($socket, $comando, strlen($comando));

$resposta = socket_read($socket, 1<<(10 * 2), PHP_NORMAL_READ);

echo $resposta;
```

Resposta:

```
{"jsonrpc": "2.0", "id": 1, "result": [{"tx_hash": "a7d790a2418fd0b17af37b2896327985d52941a1211de8705c6f16d868885412", "height": 483800}, {"tx_hash": "4ee9dcd51d1d80e6aa021e5503354ec3d4125cf8777894b68056cfef9bc9a818", "height": 483801}]}
```

---

A documentação do `socket_*` é bem precária, varias funções não tem documentação e nem sei se essa é a melhor forma. Mas, ele funciona.

Entretanto, suportar o TLS/SSL é outro assunto, isso não é suportado por esse conjunto de funções. Se houver alguma maneira ou algum outro recurso eu volto a editar essa resposta.